# Looking for strong inline verbatim environment

Tags: org-mode

By "strong" I mean that it will work unconditionally.  `'=verbatim='` does not fit the bill.  It fails, for example, in `=[[0]]=`.  Same for goes for `'~verbatim~'`.

Comment: Oddly enough, links inside code or verbatim sections are indeed exported without processing, even when displayed as links in the Org Mode buffer.

Comment: @Juancho, thanks, but I *am* interested in how things display in the org mode buffer.  There are times when I want to be able to use double square brackets without meaning them as links.  E.g. in an inline code expression of the form `a[[0]]`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a clean solution but the below hack works.

You basically break the matching for org links by introducing invisible zero-width spaces inbetween. For example, **ZWS** below is where I insert the zero-width space unicode character. You can do so by doing `C-x 8` <kbd>RET</kbd> `200b` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

```
=[​ZWS[0]]=
```

I have tested it to work for both html and pdf exports using org-mode version 8.3.2.

---

Also check out this another related QnA on emacs.stackexchange:

- [How can I escape the * in org-mode to prevent bold fontification?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16702/115)