# Org-mode: export table columns in verbatim mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

In an org-file, I have a table where I want one column to be exported verbatim:

```
|       Date | Rating | Comment    |
|------------+--------+------------|
| 2016-07-01 | ***    | so so      |
| 2016-07-08 | ****   | very good  |
| 2016-07-15 | *      | miserable! |
```

The `rating` column, consisting of a number (1-5) of stars, should be exported as verbatim or at least make the asterisks not be interpreted as **bold**.  By default, the first and third line would be nearly indistinguishable in the exported pdf file (a bold asterisk versus a normal one).

Is there a way to mark the whole column so that it is exported in verbatim mode?  Preferably the solution would still look good in plain text/org-mode.

Comment: You could try inserting zwro with space unicode character as explaines here: [Using the ZERO WIDTH SPACE unicode char](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16702/10578), although it seems to be not recommended.

Comment: It is also possible to disable all emphasis with `#+OPTIONS: *:nil` or disable specific emphasis by setting `org-emphasis-alist`, see [http://stackoverflow.com/a/22498697/1167324](here) for how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

In your table, use `\ast`, `\lowast` or `\star` from [org-entities](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html) instead of an asterix `*`.

> **Note:** Toggle viewing UTF-8 entities in org-mode with <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd>

### `\ast` exports as (*)

```
|       Date | Rating           | Comment    |
|------------+------------------+------------|
| 2016-07-01 | \ast\ast\ast     | so so      |
| 2016-07-08 | \ast\ast\ast\ast | very good  |
| 2016-07-15 | \ast             | miserable! |
#+TBLFM: $2='(replace-regexp-in-string "\\*" "\\\\ast" $2)
```

### `\lowast` exports as (∗)

```
|       Date | Rating                       | Comment    |
|------------+------------------------------+------------|
| 2016-07-01 | \lowast\lowast\lowast        | so so      |
| 2016-07-08 | \lowast\lowast\lowast\lowast | very good  |
| 2016-07-15 | \lowast                      | miserable! |
#+TBLFM: $2='(replace-regexp-in-string "\\*" "\\\\lowast" $2)
```

### `\star` exports as (*)

```
|       Date | Rating               | Comment    |
|------------+----------------------+------------|
| 2016-07-01 | \star\star\star      | so so      |
| 2016-07-08 | \star\star\star\star | very good  |
| 2016-07-15 | \star                | miserable! |
#+TBLFM: $2='(replace-regexp-in-string "\\*" "\\\\star" $2)
```

### **Hope that Helped!**

> This code was tested using
>   GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.14.13)
>   Org-mode version 8.3.5

Comment: The `replace-regexp-in-string` is especially nice. I'm thinking about trying to get this into an export filter maybe.

Answer (score 0):

> ... should be exported as verbatim...

For org-tables you must /*/ format. Enter as follows:

```
/*/ for one star
/**/ for two stars
and so on..
```

> Preferably the solution would still look good in plain text/org-mode.

After you tab out of the cell, the / will not display, which is clean for plain text viewing.

Comment: This does not seam to work, it only adds italic. Could you provide a link to a documentation that states how this is expected to work? Any options that one has to apply?

Comment: It works fine for me in tables. You are probably using something non-standard.

Comment: Not that I would know, probably it's the org version? I am using 8.3.4.

Comment: Does not work for me with a plain setup (`emacs -Q`), Emacs 24.5.1, org-mode 8.2.10.

Comment: I am sorry this also fails with `emacs -q`, which gives me 8.3.4. The slashes also have no effect in the latest version available via MELPA (8.3.5, 20160919).

Comment: `/**` works, but of course shows up on the exported document as well. I think I can live with that though.