# Prevent parsing of text inside verbatim org results block

Tags: org-export, org-babel

How do I tell emacs to not not apply treatments to text within a block like this. My issue is that, the `* foo` at the end causes the export
to go bad.
I'm using something similar to carl's setup -> https://carl.ac/blogging-with-emacs-org-github-pages/

[image]

I tried the tricks mentioned in "https://stackoverflow.com/a/39823812"

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil num:nil
#+PROPERTY: header-args :eval never-export
#+BEGIN_EXPORT html
---
layout: post
title: "Redacted"
permalink: /:title/
tags: [redacted]
---
#+END_EXPORT

Summary

#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output drawer :wrap SRC text
gem install rails_apps_composer
rails new unnamed -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC text
Fetching: i18n-0.9.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.9.5
Fetching: rails_apps_composer-3.1.36.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails_apps_composer-3.1.36
2 gems installed

      create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/administrator/unnamed/.git/
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Bundle complete! 28 Gemfile dependencies, 103 gems now installed.
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all

* foo
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: having some luck with this ZWS technique https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16702

Comment: Can you put a comma in front of the * to escape it? Or try using a verbatim block?

Comment: I've since then lost that file. Btw I'm in Westwood and big fan of your work @JohnKitchin